# Cannot access inherited property in XAML codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance

I am making a Property Sheet shell extension using [SharpShell](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell). Initially I tried using WinForms for the Property page, but the limitations of controls like PropertyGrid, ListView etc. made me choose WPF. So I created a WPF User Control Library project and added SharpShell to my project from Nuget.

I made a new Page, *I guess, I am new to VS & WPF, but it shows "Build Action" as "Page".* Now my code-behind looks like this:

```
using SharpShell.SharpPropertySheet;
using SharpShell.Attributes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FLPShellExtension
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.ClassOfExtension, ".flp")]
    public partial class FLPPropertyPage : SharpPropertyPage
    {
        public FLPPropertyPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PageTitle = "Project Info";
        }
    }
}
```

XAML looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FLPShellExtension.FLPPropertyPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:wc="clr-namespace:FLPShellExtension;assembly=SharpShell"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid></Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here, VS complains of two things:

> CS0103: The name 'PageTitle' does not exist in the current context

> XAML1103: Namespace 'wc' is unnecessary

The `PageTitle = "Project Info"` worked in WinForms. It is a `public string` defined in `SharpPropertyPage`. I found about this **wc** namespace from a similar question asked elsewhere.

Comment: You are in a userControl not a page so you don't have access to PageTitle

Comment: `<UserControl x:Class="YourClass" ...>` means that YourClass is derived from a WPF UserControl. You can't simply use something else as base class. Especially not a SharpPropertyPage that seems to be derived from a WinForms UserControl, which is something different than a WPF UserControl.

Comment: @Clemens That means I need to stick to WinForms?

Comment: @Pierre Michel I don't get what you want to say